# laravel + reactjs: links can't been clicked in deployment (with vercel)

Tags: reactjs, laravel, routes, deployment, vercel

i have found the problem but i can't found the solution.
when i use href like this in the link: {route('route.index')} it's not working (can't clicked)
when i use href like this in the link: "/login" it's working (can clicked)

like this code in below

```
<Link href={route('routines.index')}>Back</Link>

<Link href="/login" as="button">Login</Link>
```

[this example in part of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUrSW.png)

[link must to be "myproject/guide" and this image show it right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbiPI.png)

Comment: I'd like to know what is the problem with that, I mean, it seems like your problem is not clear at all. Why don't just use the second way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if its just an error in your question code snippet, but you should use double curly brackets in blade files, so change `{route('routines.index')}` to `{{ route('routines.index') }}` - If this mistake also exists in your project, this will definitely cause the broken url.

Using single curly brackets will result in `https://localhost:8080/admin/%7Broute('backend.users.list')%7D`
but with double will result in: `https://localhost:8080/admin/app-users`

Comment: i am so sorry, i have edit my question. i use react at frontend